# How to get proportions of different observation types per total and per year in pandas

Tags: pandas

I am not entirely new to data science, but rather novice with pandas.

My data looks like this:

```
    Date        Obser_Type
0   2001-01-05  A
1   2002-02-06  A
2   2002-02-06  B
3   2004-03-07  C
4   2005-04-08  B
5   2006-05-09  A
6   2007-06-10  C
7   2007-07-11  B
```

I would like to get the following output with the proportions for the different kinds of observations as of total (i.e. accumulated from the beginning up to and including the specified year) and within each year:

```
    Year    A_%_total   B_%_total   C_%_total   A_%_Year    B_%_Year    C_%_Year
0   2001    100         0           0           100         0           0
1   2002    67          33          0           50          50          0
2   2004    50          25          25          0           0           100
3   2005    40          40          20          0           100         0
4   2006    50          33          17          100         0           0
5   2007    37,5        37,5        25          0           50          50
```

I tried various approaches involving `groupby`, `multiindexing`, `count` etc but to no avail. I got either errors or something unsatisfying. 
After extensively digging Stack Overflow and the rest of the internet for days, I am stumped.

The medieval way would be a bucket of loops and ifs, but what is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have used appropriate values for the numbers. I don't know the aggregation logic of each of them, but I decided to create a composition ratio for 'Obser_Type' and a composition ratio for 'year'.

1. Add a new column for year data

2.Aggregate and create DF

3.Creating the Composition Ratio

4.Aggregate and create DF

5.Creating the Composition Ratio

6.Combining the two DF's

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
Date Obser_Type Value
0 2001-01-05 A 34
1 2002-02-06 A 39
2 2002-02-06 B 67
3 2004-03-07 C 20
4 2005-04-08 B 29
5 2006-05-09 A 10
6 2007-06-10 C 59
7 2007-07-11 B 43
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=' ')

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['yyyy'] = df['Date'].dt.year

df1 = df.groupby(['yyyy','Obser_Type'])['Value'].agg(sum).unstack().fillna(0)
df1 = df1.apply(lambda x: x/sum(x), axis=0).rename(columns={'A':'A_%_total','B':'B_%_total','C':'C_%_total'})

df2 = df.groupby(['Obser_Type','yyyy'])['Value'].agg(sum).unstack().fillna(0)
df2 = df2.apply(lambda x: x/sum(x), axis=0)
df2 = df2.unstack().unstack().rename(columns={'A':'A_%_Year','B':'B_%_Year','C':'C_%_Year'})

pd.merge(df1, df2, on='yyyy')

Obser_Type  A_%_total   B_%_total   C_%_total   A_%_Year    B_%_Year    C_%_Year
yyyy                        
2001    0.409639    0.000000    0.000000    1.000000    0.000000    0.000000
2002    0.469880    0.482014    0.000000    0.367925    0.632075    0.000000
2004    0.000000    0.000000    0.253165    0.000000    0.000000    1.000000
2005    0.000000    0.208633    0.000000    0.000000    1.000000    0.000000
2006    0.120482    0.000000    0.000000    1.000000    0.000000    0.000000
2007    0.000000    0.309353    0.746835    0.000000    0.421569    0.578431
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answer. However, i probably should have made it more clear that the actual dataframe is much bigger and has much more types of observations than A B C, so listing them manually would be inconvenient. My scope here is just the statistics for the different types of observations, not their associated numerical values.

I was able to build something and would like to share:

```
# convert dates to datetimes
#
df[‚Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[‚Date'])

# get years from the dates
#
df[‚Year'] = df.Date.dt.year

# get total number of observations per type of observation and year in tabular form
#
grouped = df.groupby(['Year', 'Obser_Type']).count().unstack(1)

                     Date 
Obser_Type  A   B     C
Year            
2001      1.0   NaN   NaN
2002      1.0   1.0   NaN
2004      NaN   NaN   1.0
2005      NaN   1.0   NaN
2006      1.0   NaN   NaN
2007      NaN   1.0   1.0

# sum total number of observations per type over all years
#
grouped.loc['Total_Obs_per_Type',:] = grouped.sum(axis=0)

                                  Date
        Obser_Type     A       B    C
              Year          
              2001   1.0    NaN    NaN
              2002   1.0    1.0    NaN
              2004   NaN    NaN    1.0
              2005   NaN    1.0    NaN
              2006   1.0    NaN    NaN
              2007   NaN    1.0    1.0
Total_Obs_per_Type   3.0    3.0    2.0

# at this point the columns have a multiindex
#
grouped.columns

    MultiIndex([('Date', 'A'),
                ('Date', 'B'),
                ('Date', 'C')],
                names=[None, 'Obser_Type'])

# i only needed the second layer which looks like this
#
grouped.columns.get_level_values(1)

    Index(['A', 'B', 'C'], dtype='object', name='Obser_Type')

# so i flattened the index
#
grouped.columns = grouped.columns.get_level_values(1)

# now i can easily address the columns
#
grouped.columns

    Index(['A', 'B', 'C'], dtype='object', name='Obser_Type')

# create list of columns with observation types 
# this refers to columns "A B C"
#
types_list = grouped.columns.values.tolist()

# create list to later access the columns with the cumulative sum of observations per type
# this refers to columns "A_cum  B_cum  C_cum"
#
types_cum_list = []

# calculate cumulative sum for the different kinds of observations
#
for columnName in types_list:
    # create new columns with modified name and calculate for each type of observation the cumulative sum of observations
    #
    grouped[columnName+'_cum'] = grouped[columnName].cumsum()

    # put the new column names in the list of columns with cumulative sum of observations per type
    #
    types_cum_list.append(columnName+'_cum')

# this gives

        Obser_Type    A     B     C  A_cum  B_cum   C_cum
              Year                      
              2001  1.0   NaN   NaN   1.0   NaN     NaN
              2002  1.0   1.0   NaN   2.0   1.0     NaN
              2004  NaN   NaN   1.0   NaN   NaN     1.0
              2005  NaN   1.0   NaN   NaN   2.0     NaN
              2006  1.0   NaN   NaN   3.0   NaN     NaN
              2007  NaN   1.0   1.0   NaN   3.0     2.0
Total_Obs_per_Type  3.0   3.0   2.0   6.0   6.0     4.0


# create new column with total number of observations for all types of observation within a single year
#
grouped['All_Obs_Y'] = grouped.loc[:,types_list].sum(axis=1)


# this gives

        Obser_Type    A     B     C  A_cum  B_cum   C_cum  All_Obs_Y
              Year                      
              2001  1.0   NaN   NaN   1.0   NaN     NaN    1.0
              2002  1.0   1.0   NaN   2.0   1.0     NaN    2.0
              2004  NaN   NaN   1.0   NaN   NaN     1.0    1.0
              2005  NaN   1.0   NaN   NaN   2.0     NaN    1.0
              2006  1.0   NaN   NaN   3.0   NaN     NaN    1.0
              2007  NaN   1.0   1.0   NaN   3.0     2.0    2.0
Total_Obs_per_Type  3.0   3.0   2.0   6.0   6.0     4.0    8.0

# create new columns with cumulative sum of all kinds observations up to each year
#
grouped['All_Obs_Cum'] = grouped['All_Obs_Y'].cumsum()

# this gives
# sorry i could not work out the formatting and i am not allowed yet to include screenshots

Obser_Type           A  B   C   A_cum   B_cum   C_cum   All_Obs_Y   All_Obs_Cum
Year                                
2001                1.0 NaN NaN 1.0 NaN NaN 1.0 1.0
2002                1.0 1.0 NaN 2.0 1.0 NaN 2.0 3.0
2004                NaN NaN 1.0 NaN NaN 1.0 1.0 4.0
2005                NaN 1.0 NaN NaN 2.0 NaN 1.0 5.0
2006                1.0 NaN NaN 3.0 NaN NaN 1.0 6.0
2007                NaN 1.0 1.0 NaN 3.0 2.0 2.0 8.0
Total_Obs_per_Type  3.0 3.0 2.0 6.0 6.0 4.0 8.0 16.0


# create list of columns with the percentages each type of observation has within the observations of each year
# this refers to columns "A_%_Y  B_%_Y  C_Y_%"
#
types_percent_Y_list = []

# calculate the percentages each type of observation has within each year
#
for columnName in types_list:

    # calculate percentages 
    #
    grouped[columnName+'_%_Y'] = grouped[columnName] / grouped['All_Obs_Y']

    # put the new columns names in list of columns with percentages each type of observation has within a year for later access
    #
    types_percent_Y_list.append(columnName+'_%_Y')

# this gives

Obser_Type  A   B   C   A_cum   B_cum   C_cum   All_Obs_Y   All_Obs_Cum A_%_Y   B_%_Y   C_%_Y
Year                                            
2001    1.0 NaN NaN 1.0 NaN NaN 1.0 1.0 1.000   NaN NaN
2002    1.0 1.0 NaN 2.0 1.0 NaN 2.0 3.0 0.500   0.500   NaN
2004    NaN NaN 1.0 NaN NaN 1.0 1.0 4.0 NaN NaN 1.00
2005    NaN 1.0 NaN NaN 2.0 NaN 1.0 5.0 NaN 1.000   NaN
2006    1.0 NaN NaN 3.0 NaN NaN 1.0 6.0 1.000   NaN NaN
2007    NaN 1.0 1.0 NaN 3.0 2.0 2.0 8.0 NaN 0.500   0.50
Total_Obs_per_Type  3.0 3.0 2.0 6.0 6.0 4.0 8.0 16.0    0.375   0.375   0.25

# replace the NaNs in the types_cum columns, otherwise the calculation of the cumulative percentages in the next step would not work
#
# types_cum_list : 
# if there is no observation for e.g. type B in the first year (2001) we put a count of 0 for that year, 
# that is, in the first row. 
# If there is no observation for type B in a later year (e.g. 2004) the cumulative count of Bs 
# from the beginning up to that year does not change in that year, so we replace the NaN there with 
# the last non-NaN value preceding it
# 
# replace NaNs in first row by 0
#
for columnName in types_cum_list:
    grouped.update(grouped.iloc[:1][columnName].fillna(value=0))
# replace NaNs in later rows with preceding non-NaN value
#
for columnName in types_cum_list:
    grouped[columnName].fillna(method='ffill' , inplace=True)

# this gives

Obser_Type  A   B   C   A_cum   B_cum   C_cum   All_Obs_Y   All_Obs_Cum A_%_Y   B_%_Y   C_%_Y
Year                                            
2001    1.0 NaN NaN 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 1.000   NaN NaN
2002    1.0 1.0 NaN 2.0 1.0 0.0 2.0 3.0 0.500   0.500   NaN
2004    NaN NaN 1.0 2.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 4.0 NaN NaN 1.00
2005    NaN 1.0 NaN 2.0 2.0 1.0 1.0 5.0 NaN 1.000   NaN
2006    1.0 NaN NaN 3.0 2.0 1.0 1.0 6.0 1.000   NaN NaN
2007    NaN 1.0 1.0 3.0 3.0 2.0 2.0 8.0 NaN 0.500   0.50
Total_Obs_per_Type  3.0 3.0 2.0 6.0 6.0 4.0 8.0 16.0    0.375   0.375   0.25


# create list of the columns with the cumulative percentages of the different observation types from the beginning up to that year
# this refers to columns "A_cum_%  B_cum_%  C_cum_%"
#
types_cum_percent_list = []


# calculate cumulative proportions of different types of observations from beginning up to each year
#
for columnName in types_cum_list:

    # if we had not taken care of the NaNs in the types_cum columns this would produce incorrect numbers
    #
    grouped[columnName+'_%'] = grouped[columnName] / grouped['All_Obs_Cum']

    # put the new columns in their respective list so we can access them conveniently later
    #
    types_cum_percent_list.append(columnName+'_%')

# this gives


Obser_Type  A   B   C   A_cum   B_cum   C_cum   All_Obs_Y   All_Obs_Cum A_%_Y   B_%_Y   C_%_Y   A_cum_% B_cum_% C_cum_%
Year                                                        
2001    1.0 NaN NaN 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 1.000   NaN NaN 1.000000    0.000000    0.000000
2002    1.0 1.0 NaN 2.0 1.0 0.0 2.0 3.0 0.500   0.500   NaN 0.666667    0.333333    0.000000
2004    NaN NaN 1.0 2.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 4.0 NaN NaN 1.00    0.500000    0.250000    0.250000
2005    NaN 1.0 NaN 2.0 2.0 1.0 1.0 5.0 NaN 1.000   NaN 0.400000    0.400000    0.200000
2006    1.0 NaN NaN 3.0 2.0 1.0 1.0 6.0 1.000   NaN NaN 0.500000    0.333333    0.166667
2007    NaN 1.0 1.0 3.0 3.0 2.0 2.0 8.0 NaN 0.500   0.50    0.375000    0.375000    0.250000
Total_Obs_per_Type  3.0 3.0 2.0 6.0 6.0 4.0 8.0 16.0    0.375   0.375   0.25    0.375000    0.375000    0.250000


# to conclude i replace the remaining NaNs to make plotting easier


# replace NaNs in columns in types_list 
#
# if there is no observation for a type of observation in a year we put a count of 0 for that year
#
for columnName in types_list:
    grouped[columnName].fillna(value=0, inplace=True)


# replace NaNs in columns in types_percent_Y_list
#
# if there is no observation for a type of observation in a year we put a percentage of 0 for that year
#
for columnName in types_percent_Y_list:
    grouped[columnName].fillna(value=0, inplace=True)




Obser_Type  A   B   C   A_cum   B_cum   C_cum   All_Obs_Y   All_Obs_Cum A_%_Y   B_%_Y   C_%_Y   A_cum_% B_cum_% C_cum_%
Year                                                        
2001    1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 1.000   0.000   0.00    1.000000    0.000000    0.000000
2002    1.0 1.0 0.0 2.0 1.0 0.0 2.0 3.0 0.500   0.500   0.00    0.666667    0.333333    0.000000
2004    0.0 0.0 1.0 2.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 4.0 0.000   0.000   1.00    0.500000    0.250000    0.250000
2005    0.0 1.0 0.0 2.0 2.0 1.0 1.0 5.0 0.000   1.000   0.00    0.400000    0.400000    0.200000
2006    1.0 0.0 0.0 3.0 2.0 1.0 1.0 6.0 1.000   0.000   0.00    0.500000    0.333333    0.166667
2007    0.0 1.0 1.0 3.0 3.0 2.0 2.0 8.0 0.000   0.500   0.50    0.375000    0.375000    0.250000
Total_Obs_per_Type  3.0 3.0 2.0 6.0 6.0 4.0 8.0 16.0    0.375   0.375   0.25    0.375000    0.375000    0.250000
```

This has the functionylity and flexibility i was looking for. But as i am still learning pandas suggestions for improvement are appreciated.